# Show that $\sin(\mathcal{o}(x)) = \mathcal{o}(x)$ as $ x\to 0$

Tags: limits, asymptotics

So I want to show that $\sin(\mathcal{o}(x)) = \mathcal{o}(x)$ as $ x\to 0$.

So far I have thought that my result will come from showing
$ \displaystyle \Big|{\frac{\sin(f(x))}{x}}\Big| \to 0$ as $x\to 0 $, where $f(x) = \mathcal{o}(x)$.

However, the only useful thing I know is that $\displaystyle\Big|{\frac{f(x)}{x}}\Big| \to 0$ as $x\to 0 $, and i'm not sure how to employ this!

I'm sure this is fairly straight forward, but I'm just not sure of the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the fact that $|\sin(x)|\le|x|$ for all $x$.

Comment: So, would it be true that $\vert\sin(f(x))\vert \leq \vert f(x) \vert $ for all $x$ also? If so, I am done!

Comment: @user142671 For **all** $x$ means that it also holds when you replace all occurences of $x$ by the same expression, so $|\sin 42|\le |42|$ and $|\sin\frac{e^t-3}{5}|\le \frac{e^t-3}{5}$ and .... $|\sin f(x)|\le |f(x)|$

Comment: wait... of course! Whoops.

Comment: Okay, how about showing $\cos(\mathcal{o}(x)) = 1 + \mathcal{o}(x)$ as $x\to0$?

Comment: You could use the relation $\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(x)$. And lo, you get $\cos(o(x))=1+o(x^2)$, which is even better.

Comment: Mean value theorem seemed to work just as well!

Comment: The mean value theorem works fine. In fact, the inequality $|\sin x|\le|x|$ is an immediate consequence of the mean value theorem applied to $\sin 0$ and $\sin x$.

Comment: Wow. I need to start noticing these things more...

Answer (score 0):

This follows from a rule of asymptotic analysis: $\,o(o(x))=o(x)$,  and $\,\sin x=o(x)$.